# Cannot construct infinite type with functor

Tags: haskell, functor

I am trying to define instances for `Functor`,`Applicative` and `Monad` for the following `type`:

```
 data BTree a=Leaf a | Node  (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving (Eq,Show)
```

I have tried implementing the `Functor` instance like this:

```
 instance Functor BTree where
        fmap f (Leaf t) =Leaf (f t)
        fmap f (Node a b) =Node (f a) (f b)
```

**What did work**

```
fmap f (Node a b)=Node (fmap f a) (fmap f b)
```

I understand it is not correct since being an instance of `functor` , the form has to be preserved `f a` -> `f b` (in our case `Node`).
and in my implementation you would get  `f a -> b`.

**What i don't understand:**

Why is it an infinite type?
Considering `Node (f a )(f b)` somewhere down the hierarchy a child  `Node` will be `Leaf`and i will apply `f` to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to apply `f` to values of type `a` (in `Leaf (f t)`) and to values of type `BTree a` (in `Node (f a) (f b)`). For this to work, the type checker needs to find some way to unify `a` and `BTree a`, which is only possible if `a` is an infinitely nested stack of `BTree` types; adding one more layer of `BTree` on top of `a` wouldn't effectively change it.

Changing `Node (f a) (f b)` to `Node (fmap f a) (fmap f b)` ensures that `f` is *only* applied to values of type `a`.

Answer (score 5):

It is an infinite type because in this case, we have `f :: (a -> b)` being applied to the left and right subtrees which have type `BTree a`.

This forces that `a` is the same as `BTree a`, which would require `a` to be an infinite type (which, for the record, you can define as `Fix BTree`, where `Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f))`, which can be useful, but not what you want here!)